# Test drag and drop behavior in a custom ViewGroup using Robotium

Tags: android, testing, drag-and-drop, tdd, robotium

I'm trying to test drag and drop behavior in my custom ViewGroup. I tried using Espresso, but it doesn't have that capability. So now I am trying with Robotium.  But my test is giving this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: This method can not be called from the main application thread

Code:

```
public void testDragAndDrop() throws Exception {
    solo.unlockScreen();

    View v = solo.getView(1);

    int width = v.getWidth();
    int height = v.getHeight();

    final float x_start = v.getX() + width/2;
    final float y_start = v.getY() + height/2;

    final float x_end = x_start + width;
    final float y_end = y_start + height;

    v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Log.d("onLongClick", "onLongClick!!");
            solo.drag(x_start, x_end, y_start, y_end, 50);
            return true;
        }
    });
    solo.clickLongOnView(v, 5000);
}
```

EDIT:

I've looked through [TouchUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html) and there are 2 methods (longClickView and drag) that, when combined, seem to do exactly what I want. So here's my version of those 2 methods combined:

```
public void longClickViewAndDrag(InstrumentationTestCase test,
                          View v,
                          float toX, float toY,
                          int stepCount) {
    int[] xy = new int[2];
    v.getLocationOnScreen(xy);

    final int viewWidth = v.getWidth();
    final int viewHeight = v.getHeight();

    float x = xy[0] + (viewWidth / 2.0f);
    float y = xy[1] + (viewHeight / 2.0f);

    Instrumentation inst = test.getInstrumentation();

    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
                                           MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
    inst.sendPointerSync(event);
    inst.waitForIdleSync();

    eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final int touchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(v.getContext()).getScaledTouchSlop();
    event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE,
                               x + touchSlop / 2, y + touchSlop / 2, 0);
    inst.sendPointerSync(event);
    inst.waitForIdleSync();

    try {
        Thread.sleep((long)(ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout() * 1.5f));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    float yStep = (toY - y) / stepCount;
    float xStep = (toX - x) / stepCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < stepCount; ++i) {
        Log.d("STEP", "..." + i);
        y += yStep;
        x += xStep;
        eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, x, y, 0);
        inst.sendPointerSync(event);
    }

    eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x, y, 0);
    inst.sendPointerSync(event);
    inst.waitForIdleSync();
}
```

For some reason the test stops after executing inst.sendPointerSync(event).

EDIT:

I've created a new post that better describes the real issue:

[Using TouchUtils in Android testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887133/using-touchutils-in-android-testing)

Comment: Note TouchUtils is now deprecatedhttps://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

[Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/) has such [method](http://robotium.googlecode.com/svn/doc/com/robotium/solo/Solo.html#drag(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20int)):

```
public void drag(
        float fromX,
        float toX,
        float fromY,
        float toY,
        int stepCount
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm trying to test code where I long click on a view and then drag it into a position without letting go off the view until it is placed over the desired position.

I tried doing clickLongOnView(View v, int time) for a specified period of time, but this method is synchronous, so the drag doesn't start until the previous method is over.

Comment: Try to update Robotium to 5. I'm not sure about this will work or not but clickOnLongView has problem with Robotium less than 4.0