# Using TouchUtils in Android testing

Tags: android, testing

I'm testing on an actual device, with the screen unlocked. Here's my code:

```
public class TouchUtilsTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    Activity mActivity;
    Instrumentation mInstrumentation;

    public TouchUtilsTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);

        mActivity = getActivity();
        mInstrumentation = getInstrumentation();
    }

    public void testTapOnView() {
        View v = mActivity.findViewById(3);
        Log.d("testTapOnView", "weee");

        TouchUtils.tapView(this, v);
    }
}
```

Even with this simple code I run into the following issue:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse, Android Studio, or something else?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio

Comment: Try [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Testing/JUnit-Gradle) and [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Testing/JUnit4) from my book. They work fine, including tests that I just ran on a Nexus 4. If they fail the same way, then I'd lean towards something odd with your device setup. If they do not fail the same way, then I'd lean towards something odd with your app (run configuration, maybe?).

Comment: Thanks, your examples seem to work just fine. Have you ever tried testing drag and drop behaviour? Whenever I long press a view, I start the drag and I believe that's what causes the INJECT_EVENTS exception.

Comment: "Have you ever tried testing drag and drop behaviour?" -- nope, sorry.